# Google Places Address Lookup not working

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm having an issue with the Googlemaps API, specifically the places library. This is all using WordPress.

I've built a sign up form here: http://dabble.market/cms/sign-up/

I replicated exactly what I built in my localhost. I have the bottom field labelled: "Address which will be shown on the our map. Start typing & choose from the list." hooked up to the Googlemaps API using the places library. It then ran Google's address lookup / autocomplete on it perfectly fine. Once the Address autocomplete ran, it served the full address and lat / lng coords back to the user using the JS written below.

Now that I've migrated it over to a live version of the site, the address lookup functionality no longer works.

Any help would be really appreciated thanks.

```
var address, latitude, longitude, addressString;

function initialize() {
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    var options = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: "nz"}
    };
    var input = document.getElementById('txtPlaces');

    var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = places.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            jQuery('#error').css("display", "inherit");         
            return;
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#error').css("display", "none");            
        }

        address = place.formatted_address;
        latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

        addressString = "Address: " + address + "\n" + "Latitude: " + latitude + "\n" + "Longitude: " + longitude;

        jQuery('#geocoords-hidden').val(addressString);

        jQuery('#addressContainer').css("display", "inherit");
        jQuery('#addressInfo').text("Address: " + address);
        jQuery('#addressInfo1').text("Latitude: " + latitude);
        jQuery('#addressInfo2').text("Longitude: " + longitude);        
    });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I've figured it out.

```
I removed the function initialize() {  ...  }
```

and replaced it with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  ...  });
```